# Spying on Backbone.js route calls with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine

Having problems spying method calls on a Backbone Router to ensure it calles the right method on a given route.

excerpt from the test

```
describe 'Router', ->
    beforeEach ->
        @router = new App.Router()
        Backbone.history.start()

    afterEach ->
        Backbone.history.stop()

    describe 'routes', ->
         it 'should be defined', ->
              expect(@router.routes).toBeDefined()

         describe 'default route', ->
             it 'should be defined', ->
                  expect(@router.routes['']).toBeDefined()

             it 'should call index', ->
                 spy = spyOn(@router, "index")
                 @router.navigate('', true)
                 expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

The router

```
class App.Router extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        '' : 'index'

    index: ->
        console.log "router.index has been called"
```

Everything passes except the last test "should call index". 
It fails with the message "Expected spy index to have been called".
Ive tried other variants

```
it "should call index", ->
    spyOn(@router, "index")
    @router.navigate('', true)
    expect(@router.index).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

I can also see the "router.index has been called" log output in the test output from the original Router.index function

Thanks!

EDIT:
One solution

```
describe '#1 Solution', ->
    it 'should call index', ->
        spyOn(App.Router.prototype, "index")
        @router = new App.Router()
        Backbone.history.start()
        @router.navigate('', true)
        expect(App.Router.prototype.index).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has took too much time to me to come with a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/4Ndgc/) and the question has been already answered by @MarkRushakoff.

Still I have some comments.

The way Backbone is binding the routes make very difficult to test it.

The point is that the router *methods* are not called directly in the router *instance*, the methods are taked as *callbacks* and stored in an internal `Backbone.history.route` waiting for execution, [check the Backbone.Router.route code](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L911-922).

This operation is done in the moment the `Router` is instantiate, so you have to `spy` your *Router.method* before you instantiate the reference, so for you have to delay `Backbone.history.start` also after the `spy` has been activated.

As you have to declare the `spy` before the router instance is created you have to do it in a *Class* level.

Said so this is the simplest solution I came with:

```
describe("Router", function() {
  afterEach( function(){
    Backbone.history.stop();
  });

  it("should call index", function(){
    spyOn(App.Router.prototype, "index")
    var router = new App.Router(); // instance created after spy activation
    Backbone.history.start();      // it has to start after the Router instance is created

    router.navigate('', true);

    expect(App.Router.prototype.index).toHaveBeenCalled();  
  });
});
```

Conclusion, I think the `Backbone.Router` implementation has not an intuitive design.

Comment: This is not a viable way to test the triggering of a route.  All this is testing is that the index function was bound to the router as a callback, not that the function is actually called when the route was triggered.  See [this S.O. post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215737/testing-routers-in-backbone-js-properly) for how to verify that the corresponding route function was called when a router matches a url.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the way that Backbone binds to its routing methods when you use a routes hash (especially if you're seeing a console log correctly output). That is, the router has bound to the original `index` method, but your spy has replaced the "current" `index` method.

You have two options:

- `spyOn(@router, "index")` before you the router binds to the routes (may be difficult)
- Spy on the prototype's `index` method: `spyOn(App.router.prototype, "index"); @router.navigate('', true); expect(App.router.prototype.index).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: Thanks, that works :) Option number two is viable. The spy needs to be added before a new instance of the router is made. I guess thats OK!

Comment: Option one I think is not possible due the _routes binding_ is done in the _initialize_ so in the moment you have a reference to the instance the binding has been already done.