# Test a Form submission with jasmine and backbone.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

I want to test the Form submission by using jasmine.
The form is defined in a backbone view which looks like this (1).
I implemented the following test (2), but I am not sure how it is effective.
For example if the textarea is empty onError function should be called.
Any ideas the best way to test the submission of a form, in this context, by using jasmine?

---

(1)

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'focus [data-tid="message"]' : 'focusForm',
        'blur [data-tid="message"]' : 'blurForm',
        'submit   form' : 'submitForm'
    },

    focusedClass: 'is-form-focused',

    focusForm: function () {
        this.$el.find('form').addClass(this.focusedClass);
    },

    blurForm: function () {
        this.$el.find('form').removeClass(this.focusedClass);
    },

    submitForm: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formElement =  event.currentTarget,
            message = this.$el.find('.message');

        if (formElement.checkValidity && !formElement.checkValidity()) {
            this.onError();
        } else {
            // makes a POST ajax call
            backendController.submitFeedback(message.val()).done(this.onSuccess).fail(this.onError);

        }
    },

    onError: function () {
        this.$el.find('.message').focus();
    },

    onSuccess: function () {
        this.$el.find('.message').val('');
        this.$el.find('form').removeClass(this.focusedClass);
    }
});
```

---

(2)

```
describe('When Submit button handler fired', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        this.popupSpy = sinon.spy();
        this.view.render();
        this.view.$el.find('form').on('submit', this.popupSpy);
        this.view.$el.find('form').trigger('submit');
    });
    it('submitForm should be called', function () {
        expect(this.popupSpy.callCount).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you are testing your own test.

I rather would propose something like this:

```
// code simplified and no tested
describe("When Submit button handler fired", function () {
  it("submitForm should be called", function () {
    this.view.render();
    spyOn( this.view, "submitForm" );
    this.view.$el.find("form").submit();
    expect( this.view.submitForm ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

#### Update

Probably my above code is not gonna work, due like in [spying over Router methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847339/spying-on-backbone-js-route-calls-with-jasmine/11849364#11849364) the handlers are seted at initializing time so any further `spy` is not gonna be called.

You should spy at class level and before you have instantiated your View:

```
// code simplified and no tested
describe("When Submit button handler fired", function () {
  it("submitForm should be called", function () {
    spyOn( MyView.prototype, "submitForm" );

    this.view = new MyView();
    this.view.render();

    this.view.$el.find("form").submit();

    expect( MyView.prototype.submitForm ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your response. Actually I get the following error `Expected spy submitForm to have been called` are you sure about the code you wrote?. thanks

Comment: _// code simplified and no tested_ ;).. I'm just offering an starting point, likely you should clean up a little bit.

Comment: I can work in a _working example_ but you should offer me a playground, you can fork [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/63WPu/).

Comment: @LorraineBernard check my update. And if it still not working check my above comment.

Comment: this time it seems to work, but there is a huge problem: I get an infinite loop on the page browser which is making the test :(