# createSpy not overriding in Backbone Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, bdd, jasmine

I am trying to test my Jasmine edit view. One of the tests I need to complete tests the submit button event is properly wired up. I simply need to set up the rendered content and then submit the form, testing that the save method is then being called as expected.

Here's the test code...

```
define(['spec-helper', 'views/about/v-edit-version-info-entry', 'models/m-version-info'],
function (Helper, View, VersionInfo) {
    describe("Version Info Editor View", function () {

        var objUt;

        beforeEach(function() {
            objUt = new View();
            $('body').append('<div id="jasmineSpecTestArea"></div>');
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            $('#jasmineSpecTestArea').remove();
        });

        it("is appropriately named", function() {
            expect(objUt.name).toEqual('Edit Version Info');
        });

        it("is wrapped in the appropriate container", function() {
            expect(objUt.el.outerHTML.toLowerCase()).toContain('<div class="edit-version-info-panel">');
        });

        it("triggers save when the form is submitted", function () {
            objUt.collection = new VersionInfo.Collection();

            spyOnEvent($('.edit-version-info-form'), 'submit');
            objUt.saveEntry = jasmine.createSpy('saveEntry() spy');

            objUt.render();
            $('#jasmineSpecTestArea').append(objUt.el);
            $('.edit-version-info-form').submit();

            expect('submit').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn($('.edit-version-info-form'));
            expect(objUt.saveEntry).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

The last of the tests is the problematic one. It seems that the jasmine.createSpy call does not replace the saveEntry method that is then called by the underlying event in the object. Here's the class I'm trying to test...

```
define(['ministry', 'models/m-version-info', 'text!templates/version-info/edit-version-info-entry.html', 'jquery.custom'],
function (Ministry, VersionInfo, TemplateSource) {

    var editVersionInfoView = Ministry.View.extend({

        name: 'Edit Version Info',

        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'edit-version-info-panel',

        template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateSource),

        $dbVersionInput: undefined,
        $tagInput: undefined,

        initialize: function () {
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            this.$dbVersionInput = this.$('#dbVersion');
            this.$tagInput = this.$('#tag');
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'submit .edit-version-info-form': 'saveEntry'
        },

        createModelInstance: function(options) {
            return new VersionInfo.Model(options);
        },

        saveEntry: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newEntry = this.createModelInstance({ dbVersion: this.$dbVersionInput.val(), tag: this.$tagInput.val() });
            this.collection.create(newEntry);
        }
    });

    return editVersionInfoView;
});
```

Any advice would be most welcome, I can't figure out why my createSpy isn't overriding it. Is this some weirdness with the Backbone events system that I can't get around? If so it kind of makes a lot of testing in the front end area useless, as the tests are trying (but failing) to save data to the API!!

Comment: You should add the answer in an actual answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I tried to, but I'm not allowed to yet

Comment: Seems I now have the rights to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this under another post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953393/test-a-form-submission-with-jasmine-and-backbone?rq=1)) and changed the assertion accordingly...

```
it("triggers save when the form is submitted", function () {
    View.prototype.saveEntry = jasmine.createSpy('saveEntry() spy').andCallFake(Helper.PreventedEvent);
    objUt = new View();
               
    spyOnEvent($('.edit-version-info-form'), 'submit');

    objUt.render();
    $('#jasmineSpecTestArea').append(objUt.el);
    $('.edit-version-info-form').submit();

    expect('submit').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn($('.edit-version-info-form'));
    expect(objUt.saveEntry).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

... the key was attaching the createSpy and a callFake to the prototype before creating the instance. (Try it without the fake on a submit event for flashy screen fun!!) Helper.PreventedEvent simply returns a simple function that prevents the submission by calling preventDefault.

Interestingly the jasmine-jquery expect('submit') now fails. This may well be because of the faking and isn't critical as I can test execution by the fact the method is called.