# Testing backbone router with jasmine and sinon. Cannot call the pushState.

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, backbone-routing, sinon

I was following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215737/testing-routers-in-backbone-js-properly) to test the router. My router is really simple:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "": "index",
        "help": "help"
    },

    help: function() {/* not really needed */ },

    index: function(){
        // does something
    }   
});
```

And this is an apptempted translation of what should be the test using jasmine with sinon:

```
it('triggers the "index" route', function() {
    var router = new App.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
        //Not calling navigate it's a problem
    router.navigate('help', {
        trigger : true, replace: true
    });
    var index = sinon.spy(router, 'index');

    var spyHasPS = sinon.spy(function(
            data, title, url) {
        expect(url).toEqual('/');
        router.index();
    }); 

    var spyNoPS = sinon.spy(function(loc, frag) {
        expect(frag).toEqual('');
        router.index(); 
    });

    if (Backbone.history._hasPushState) {
        pushStateSpy = sinon.stub(window.history, 'pushState', spyHasPS );
    //  window.history.pushState();
    } else if (Backbone.history._wantsHashChange) {
        pushStateSpy = sinon.stub(Backbone.history, '_updateHash', spyNoPS);
        //Backbone.history._updateHash(window.location, '');
    }

    router.navigate('', {
        trigger : true, replace: true
    });
    expect(pushStateSpy.called).toBe(true);
    expect(index.called).toBe(true);

});
```

This test works but I could achieve it because I navigated first on "help". "help" was just something I created to pass the test but the original question didn't do it and was passing. Did I do something wrong? I also run his test but the error I'm getting is:

```
    Expected spy _updateHash to have been called.   Error: Expected spy
 _updateHash to have been called.
    at null.<anonymous> (/src/test/js/spec/wfcRouter.spec.js:65:32)     Expected spy index to have been called.
```

I believe the "problem" is in the navigate function. At a certain point in the `navigate: function(fragment, options)` we have this control:

```
 fragment = this.getFragment(fragment || '');
  if (this.fragment === fragment) return;
```

So...does it make sense to test the pushState when you just have one route (remember I added "help" just to make this test pass so I don't need it)? If it does make sense, how can I achieve this test?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are testing is Backbone code, but there's no need for you to test that: presumably the Backbone code has been tested plenty by Jeremy Ashkenas (and if you look at the Backbone project on GitHub you will see that he does in fact have a comprehensive test suite). So, rather than re-testing code you didn't write that's already been tested, what you really should be testing is the code *you* wrote.

If you agree with that principle, then you can simplify your test a great deal, down to just:

```
it('triggers the "index" route', function() {
    var router = new App.Router();

    router.index(); 
    expect(thingThatShouldHaveHappenedInIndexRouteDidHappen).toBe(true);
});
```